# Contour integral for integrand with branch point

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, branch-points

I'd like to solve $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{x(x+1)}dx,$ where $\alpha \in (0,1).$ The answer is  $\frac{\pi}{\sin (\alpha \pi)}.$

Typically, to solve it, we use contour integral and residue theorem as follows. Let $C=C_{r}^R-I_{r,R}^- -C_r+I_{r,R}^+$ denote the simple closed positively oriented contour, where $-C_r$ and $C_{r}^R$ are the portions of the circles $C_r(0)$ and $C_R(0)$, respectively, and $-I_{r,R}^-$ and $I_{r,R}^+$ the horizontal segments joining them. We select a small value of $r$ and a large value of $R$ so that the nonzero poles $-1$ of $\displaystyle f(z):=\frac{z^\alpha}{z (z+1)}$ lie inside $C.$  We use the branch of $z^\alpha$ corresponding to the branch of the logarithm $\log_0$ as follows:

$\displaystyle z^\alpha=e^{\alpha \log_0 (z)} =|z|^\alpha e^{i \alpha\theta}$ for $z=re^{i\theta}\neq 0$ and $\theta \in (0,2\pi]$

Then $\displaystyle \int_C f(z)dz=\int_{C_{r}^R}f(z)dz-\int_{I_{r,R}^-}f(z)dz -\int_{C_r}f(z)dz+\int_{I_{r,R}^+}f(z)dz.$

Using the residue theorem,
    \begin{equation}\label{8-29}
\int_C f(z)dz=2\pi i \textrm{Res}[f,-1].
\end{equation}
 On the other hand, $\displaystyle \lim_{r\to 0^+}\int_{C_r^R}f(z)dz=\int_{C_R^+(0)}f(z)dz$, and it can be shown that $\displaystyle\lim_{r \to 0^+} \int_{C_r}f(z)=\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{C_R^+(0)}f(z)dz=0,$ by M-L inequlity.

My question arises in the next part (most textbooks don't explain it in detail):

**Because of the branch we chose for $z^\alpha,$  $\displaystyle \lim_{r\to 0^+} \int_{I_{r,R}^+}f(z)dz=\int_0^R\frac{x^\alpha}{x(x+1)}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{r\to 0^+} \int_{I_{r,R}^-}f(z)dz=\int_0^R\frac{x^\alpha e^{i\alpha 2\pi}}{x(x+1)}$. Note that since $Q$ has a zero of order at most $1$ at the origin, the above two integrals converge.**

I understand that the integrand $f(z)$ on the upper horizontal line approaches $\frac{x^\alpha}{x(x+1)}$, where $x$ is a real number. Similarly, $f(z)$ on the lower horizontal line approaches $\frac{x^\alpha e^{i\alpha 2\pi}}{x(x+1)}$.

I'd like to prove $\displaystyle \lim_{r\to 0^+} \int_{I_{r,R}^+}f(z)dz=\int_0^R\frac{x^\alpha P(x)}{Q(x)}$ in detail.

What theorem do I use for this equality. Do I use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem?

I appreciate if you give any comments about it. Thanks in advance.